# My prefix is a type of car, my suffix means you can’t see far

Tags: riddle, word, rhyme

An original riddle:

> My prefix is a type of car.
>   My suffix means you can’t see far.
>   My infix concerns the outside.
>   Together, I remove the inside.

What am I?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You are a:

> **TAXIDERMIST**

*My prefix is a type of car.*

> A **TAXI** is a type of car.

*My suffix means you can’t see far.*

> When there is **MIST** your field of vision is limited and "*you can't see far*".

*My infix concerns the outside.*

> The **DERMIS** is another word for the skin, i.e. the *outside* of a body or fruit, etc.

*Together, I remove the inside.*

> The role of a taxidermist is quite literally to '*remove the inside*' of a deceased animal and replace it with a packing material, to preserve it as a lifelike representation for all time...

Comment: That is correct :)

Comment: Referring to a taxidermist as an "animal inside remover" actually makes them sound even more creepy in an already creepy profession.

Comment: @JPhi1618 Might want to use a vague word like "them", so as not to spoil it for people by accident

Comment: or use rot13 https://rot13.com/